# Is there a simple way to check if a mail backend is valid in Django without sending a mail?

Tags: python, django, smtp

In my tool the users can provide a mail backend using certain infos on a model and send their mails via the backend which gets created from those values. This all works, but I would love to have a quick check if the provided backend actually will work before using it. Using something like this `check_mail_connection` doesn't work as this actually returns False even though I entered valid connection parameters.

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_mail_connection(self, fail_silently=False)
        return get_connection(host=self.email_host,
                   port=self.email_port,
                   username=self.email_username,
                   password=self.email_password ... )

    def check_mail_connection(self) -> bool:
        from socket import error as socket_error
        from smtplib import SMTP, SMTPConnectError
        smtp = SMTP(host=self.email_host, port=self.email_port)
        try:
            smtp.connect()
            return True
        except SMTPConnectError:
            return False
        except socket_error:
            return False
```

I don't want to send a test mail to confirm, as this can easily get lost or fail on a different part of the system. This feature is for sending out emails from the users mail servers, as I suspect most of my users have a mail server anyways and I basically offer white labeling and similar stuff to them.

Comment: Rather creative stuff you have. Obviously, I don't have all of the details but, I am curious on did you look at the point of where the user first sends the information to the server as a weak point? If I were a government official or a hacker, I would break the SSL encryption prior to it hitting the server and walk everything back from there. It's possible to lock people out at that point as well but, now your looking at devices being compromised and the layers for that. I don't know what you built so I can't go further.

Comment: As a work around you could use Console backend. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: @SohailAQ No I shouldn't. I try to check the validity of an SMPT config. I know that the rest works. If the config is valid everything works, I just want the user to see if the config works before they use it.

Comment: @Boheyga please check out the updated question as I try to clear up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following line `smtp.connect()` in your code that attempts to make a connection. If you look at the [documentation for smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.connect) the signature for this method is:

> ```py
> SMTP.connect(host='localhost', port=0)
> ```

Meaning you are trying to connect to `localhost` with port 25 (standard SMTP port). Of course there is no server listening there and you get a `ConnectionRefusedError` which you catch and return `False`. In fact you don't even need to call `connect` because the documentation states:

> If the optional host and port parameters are given, the SMTP
> `connect()` method is called with those parameters during
> initialization.

Hence you can simply write:

```
def check_mail_connection(self) -> bool:
    from smtplib import SMTP
    try:
        smtp = SMTP(host=self.email_host, port=self.email_port)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False
```

You can also simply use the `open` method of the email backend's instance rather than creating the `SMTP` instance and calling `connect` yourself:

```
def check_mail_connection(self) -> bool:
    try:
        email_backend = self.get_mail_connection()
        silent_exception = email_backend.open() is None
        email_backend.close()
        return not silent_exception
    except OSError:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works, the second one however returns False for a valid config. Trying to debug this, but as the first one works, I will likely just use this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions for you and would like for you to answer these questions before we can go further.

What type of OS are you running the server on?
What mail client and tutorial did you follow? Postfix?
Can a user on the server send local mail to another user on the server?
What ports are open and what type of security features do you have installed?
What did your logs say when the email failed?
Are you self hosting/ are you acting as the server admin?
(It's fine if this is your first time. Everyone had a first day.)

SSL and A FQDN isn't too important if your just sending mail out. The system will still work, you just won't be able to receive mail.

(I'm talking from the sense of making sure it at least will send an email. You should at least use SSL as it can be gotten for free.)

If you checked all of these things, there is a part of the mail client that you are using and it probably won't send mail out unless it has approval. There are a lot of variables.

All of these things matter or it wont work.

Sorry meant to make this as a comment. I'm not use to speaking on here.

Comment: The server runs dockerized with Alpine. I followed the Django source code and Docs. No, users can't send mails to each other. This is more for whitelabeling and using the own mail servers of a company. SSL is possible, I just cut it so that the question is a minimal viable example. Like I said it works fine, if the config is correct and doesn't work, if the config is false. As we only send mails using this backend, all the outgoing ports are open.

Comment: I'm here. Abdul Aziz Barkat did a good job. I like to first get an understanding of how you configured this process.  For instance, you may have some emails fail because "   DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE. Default: 2621440 (i.e. 2.5 MB). The maximum size in bytes that a request body may be before a SuspiciousOperation ( RequestDataTooBig ) is raised. The check is done when accessing request. " Thus, you may want to look at this and all of the possibilities of what your product can generate.